# Problems with URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm trying access my application but here is the error:

> The requested URL /app/auth/login was not found on this server.

this is the `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The folder `app` contains my php application in `codeigniter`.

`config.php`

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.0.150/app/';`

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: comment this htaccess file and check

Comment: what is the location of your .htaccess file? it should in app folder

Comment: replace this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: pradeep, yes it's inside the app folder. Same error after replace.

Comment: have u loaded url helper?

Comment: Yes... its loaded

Comment: ok can you show your route.php

Comment: Yes.. i've edited.

Comment: Any idea? when the url have index.php, it works

Comment: it is working with my side

Comment: in xampp it works but in production server not working

Answer (score 0):

Add RewriteBase /app/ to your .htaccess file.

Here is an example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /app

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Some configuration in apache?

Comment: Just tried this with a test setup - and the RewriteBase /app makes mine work. Is ModRewrite working when CodeIgniter is setup as the root app? Can you test that in another test application?

Comment: What do you mean? CodeIgniter is setup as the root app?

Comment: You have your base url set as "http://192.168.0.150/app/", meaning your "app" is not set as the root. Its a child of the root.

So i'm curious if you set your virtual host to point to the "app" folder itself, if it would work.

Comment: ok... you mean.. when type "192.168.0.150" automatically point to 192.168.0.150/app/ ?

Comment: yeah, so you wouldn't need the "app/" at the end of your URL.

You using apache?

Point your virtual host config file to point to your "app" directory.

Then all you should have to type in is http :// 192.168.0.150 and it'll goto your app directory.

Comment: Just change your RewriteBase to "/" then when you make that change.

Comment: i cant do that, because i'll use that server for others apps in others folders

Comment: Thats why I wanted you to create a test virtual host - and point it to your "app" directory. To make sure ModRewrite is working for you.

Comment: I have a working site, call it mytestsite.com. In it I have created an "app/" directory, and created a codeigniter project in there. With the above .htaccess file I gave you, I'm able to access this project with mytestsite.com/app, and I'm still able to access different controllers, and another method within the non-default controller. If you already have a virtualhost pointing to mytestsite.com - all you should have to do is add your .htaccess file in your "app/" directory.

Comment: honestly... i dont have idea how to do that.. it's the first time in apache server.. shame on me...

Comment: no problem at all. in /etc/apache2/sites-available, you should have some *.conf files that are used to point to specific directories on your server. One of these is probably pointing to /var/www/[your web directory]. If this site is already enabled, you don't have to do anything with this anymore.. you can check by going to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, and seeing if that same .conf file is listed there. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Hello @user115812, considering our long discussion here and in the private chat, if this has helped you, would you mind accepting this answer or even up voting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working Example

Example: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If still not working

Please add below line in 000-default.conf

```
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

(File Path For Ubuntu: /etc/apache2/sites-available) and restart apache

Comment: my app is inside "app" folder... i'll try

Comment: ok if still not working try CI URI Routing
 https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html